# Ant equivalent for IntelliJ's "provided" scope

Tags: java, android, ant, intellij-idea

For Android and other Java projects, IntelliJ and some other build systems allow for dependencies with scope "Provided", meaning the sources of the dependent module will not be included in the module in question.

While IntelliJ sets up the Ant project.properties on the basis of the module configuration, it includes only what IntelliJ calls "compile" dependencies, so the "provided" dependencies will result in build errors when using Ant.

"Provided" scope is useful in cases where other dependency scopes would lead to classes being referenced multiple times.

Is there a way of doing something like this in Ant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure Ant does not do dependency management, its just a build tool. IntelliJ covers this up by generating an appropriate build script based on your project configuration, but thats just a crutch.

In order to mimic the same thing outside of the IDE environment you need to rely on extensions to Ant - aka [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/). Ivy brings dependency management to the Ant build 'table', allowing you to define libraries to be used in your build and how they should be scoped. The [Ivy Quick Start](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/start.html) is a good place to begin in learning it.

Alternatively, you could use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/), which *is* a dependency management tool, and works as-is out-of-the box with no additional configuration needed. Plus, its supported in IntelliJ.